# Titanium memory leak in master/detail demo application

Tags: memory-leaks, titanium, master-detail

I had little experience with titanium. Basically I need master/detail application same as demo version available at [git](https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/Template.MasterDetail) or in sample titaniumstudio

Here is the part which i think has leak

```
masterView.addEventListener('itemSelected', function(e) {
    //create detail view container
    var detailView = new DetailView();
    var detailContainerWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:'Product Details',
    navBarHidden:false,
    backgroundColor:'#ffffff'
    });
    detailContainerWindow.add(detailView);
    detailView.fireEvent('itemSelected',e);
    detailContainerWindow.open();
});
```

Logically Every time when the table row click,a detailview should be created and will destroy on back button press. But as tested on android device .. on every click of tableview memory taken by this application was increased. I think titanium taking new detailview every time but not destroying the old one which is keep running in backend.
please tell me if is it a bug or i had mistaken something.

Comment: Can't you create a window outside the event and create/add detail view inside the event?

Comment: @Muhammad Zeeshan Yes I had tried for it. Because its great to use same window every time. but it gives me another strange behavior.. It runs for the first time but from the next time it is showing the blank window. If we put the alert in handling event. it fired the alert but application is still blank.

Comment: Are you closing the window on back button event?

Comment: No, I had used only the sample application code. there is no back button event code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for all my memory problems with this:

```
var memPool = Ti.UI.createWindow();
memPool.open();
memPool.hide();
memPool.add(yourTrashView);    
memPool.close();
```

Explained here:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/116867/this-is-a-solution-to-your-memory-woes

Comment: hey Mike thanks for the Answer.. I had seen this link before..
I need to Open 2 windows which will swap focusing on each other with an event occurrence ..on Swap, emulator showing new resources are loading which I think real reason for this memory increased. Ending Up with your solution which includes quite delay in app.. hope it resolve in new mobilesdk version..

Comment: I use this solution in the same situation (with some webviews in the detailView) and I dont have problems with delay. I think you should try.